# Is proposed "matrix sieve" algorithm useful?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I propose "matrix sieve" algorithm for finding primes that  is simple and easy to memorize:

In order to find all primes (up to a given limit) in the sequence 
$S1(p)=6p+5, (p=0, 1, 2, 3,...)$:

Step 1a. Starting from 5 cross out each 5th member of the row of positive integers$ N(n)=0,1,2,3,4,...$, i.e remove the following integers:
 5, 10, 15,...

Step 1b. Starting from 5 cross out each 7th member of the row of positive integers, i.e remove the following integers: 5, 12, 19,..

Step 2a.Starting from 23 cross out each 11th member of the row of positive integers, i.e remove the following integers: 23, 34, 45,...

Step 2b. .Starting from 23 cross out each 13th member of the row of positive integers, i.e remove the following integers 23, 36, 49,...

.........

Step ia. Starting from $(6i^2−1)$ cross out each $(6i−1)th$ member of the row of positive integers.

Step ib. Starting from $(6i^2−1)$ cross out each $(6i+1)th$ member of the row of positive integers.

Remaining members of $N(n)$ are indexes p of all primes (up to a given limit) in the sequence $S1(p)=6p+5$:
$p=0,1,2,3,4,...,6,7,8,9,...,11,..,13,14,....,16..... $and primes are $5,11,17,23,29,...,41,47,53,59,...,71,...,83,89,...$

In order to find all (up to a given limit) primes in the sequence 
$S2(p)=6p+7, (p=0, 1, 2, 3,...)$:

Step 1a. Starting from 3 cross out each 5th member of the row of positive integers, i.e remove the following integers 3,8,13,...

Step 1b. .Starting from 7 cross out each 7th member of the row of positive integers, i.e remove the following integers 7,14,21,...

Step 2a.Starting from 19 cross out each 11th member of the row of positive integers, i.e remove the following integers 19,30,41,...

Step 2b. .Starting from 27 cross out each 13th member of the row of positive integer, i.e remove the following integers 27,40,53,...

.........

Step ia.Starting from $(6i^2−1−2i)$ cross out each $(6i−1)th$ member of the row of positive integers.

Step ib.Starting from $(6i^2−1+2i)$ cross out each $(6i+1)th$ member of the row of positive integers.

Remaining members of $N(n)$ are indexes p of all primes (up to a given limit) in the sequence $S2(p)=6p+7$:
$p=0,1,2,..,4,5,6,..,9,10,11,12,...,15,16....$ and primes are$ 7,13,19,...,31,37,43,...,61,67,73,79,...,97,103,....﻿$

Comment: Isn't this just a restriction of the regular Eratosthenes sieve?

Comment: @nuslundx  No it's not. All we have  to  do is to find positive integers which do not appear in two pairs of arrays:  $A1(i,j)=6i^2-1+(6i- 1)(j-1);  A2(i,j)=6i^2-1+(6i+ 1)(j-1);                  A3(i,j)=6i^2-1-2i+(6i- 1)(j-1);   A4(i,j)=6i^2-1+2i+(6i+ 1)(j-1),  i,j=1, 2, 3,..... $